# Numpy: Creation of a variable length sequence from a pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Lets say that I have the following data frame:

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame({"person_id": [101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103], "date": [0, 5, 0, 7, 11, 0], "val1": [99, 11, 22, 33, 44, 22], "val2": [77, 88, 22, 66, 55, 33]})
```

What I want to achieve is create a 3 dimensional numpy array such that the result should be the following:

```
np_pros = np.array([[[0, 99, 77], [5, 11, 88]], [[0, 22, 22], [7, 33, 66], [11, 44, 55]], [[0, 22, 33]]])
```

In other words, the 3D array should have the following shape `[unique_ids, None, feature_size]`. In my case, the number of `unique_ids` is 3, the `feature size` is 3 (all columns except the `person_id`), and the `y` column is of variable length and it indicates the number of measurments for a `person_id`.

I am well aware that I can create an `np.zeros((unique_ids, max_num_features, feature_size))` array, populate it and then delete the elements that I don't need but  I want something faster. The reason being is that my actual data-frame is huge (roughly `[50000, 455]`) which will result in a numpy array of roughly [12500, 200, 455].

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: I don't think you can create an array like that, each of the inner array have different sizes, the group size. You could have a list however.

Comment: @DanielMesejo so what do you suggest? What would be optimal in both memory and complexity?

Comment: What do you want to do afterwards?

Comment: Thats a good question. After I have the sequences I want to perform bucketing with Tensorflow to dynamically pad the sequences.

Comment: Thats why I strictly want to end up with a variable length array (to pad afterwards within a batch).

Comment: Could you add what the output looks after is being padded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186487/discussion-between-gorjan-and-daniel-mesejo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
ix = np.flatnonzero(df1.person_id != df1.person_id.shift(1))
np.split(df1.drop('person_id', axis=1).values, ix[1:])

[array([[ 0, 99, 77],
        [ 5, 11, 88]], dtype=int64), 
 array([[ 0, 22, 22],
        [ 7, 33, 66],
        [11, 44, 55]], dtype=int64), 
 array([[ 0, 22, 33]], dtype=int64)]
```

**Details**

Use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) after comparing `df1` with a shifted version of itself ([`pd.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)) in order to get the indices where changes in `person_id` take place:

```
ix = np.flatnonzero(df1.person_id != df1.person_id.shift(1))
#array([0, 2, 5])
```

Use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) in order to split the dataframe's columns of interest according to the obtained index:

```
np.split(df1.drop('person_id', axis=1).values, ix[1:])

[array([[ 0, 99, 77],
        [ 5, 11, 88]], dtype=int64), 
 array([[ 0, 22, 22],
        [ 7, 33, 66],
        [11, 44, 55]], dtype=int64), 
 array([[ 0, 22, 33]], dtype=int64)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df_raw = pd.DataFrame({"person_id": [101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103], "date": [0, 5, 0, 7, 11, 0], "val1": [99, 11, 22, 33, 44, 22], "val2": [77, 88, 22, 66, 55, 33]})

result = [group.values for _, group in df_raw.groupby('person_id')[['date', 'val1', 'val2']]]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[array([[  0, 101,  99,  77],
       [  5, 101,  11,  88]]), array([[  0, 102,  22,  22],
       [  7, 102,  33,  66],
       [ 11, 102,  44,  55]]), array([[  0, 103,  22,  33]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/)

---

Let's ***create the dimension implied by the duplicity of `person_id`***

```
>>> df['newdim'] = df.person_id.duplicated()
>>> df.newdim    = df.groupby('person_id').newdim.cumsum()
>>> df           = df.set_index(["newdim", "person_id"])
>>> df
                  date  val1  val2
newdim person_id                  
0.0    101           0    99    77
1.0    101           5    11    88
0.0    102           0    22    22
1.0    102           7    33    66
2.0    102          11    44    55
0.0    103           0    22    33
```

***For the sake of readability***, we may want to turn `df` into an [`xarray.Dataset`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.html)-object

```
>>> xa = df.to_xarray()
>>> xa
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (newdim: 3, person_id: 3)
Coordinates:
  * newdim     (newdim) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0
  * person_id  (person_id) int64 101 102 103
Data variables:
    date       (newdim, person_id) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 7.0 nan nan 11.0 nan
    val1       (newdim, person_id) float64 99.0 22.0 22.0 11.0 33.0 nan nan ...
    val2       (newdim, person_id) float64 77.0 22.0 33.0 88.0 66.0 nan nan ...
```

and then into a ***dimensionally-healthy*** numpy array

```
>>> ar = xa.to_array().T.values
>>> ar
array([[[ 0., 99., 77.],
        [ 5., 11., 88.],
        [nan, nan, nan]],

       [[ 0., 22., 22.],
        [ 7., 33., 66.],
        [11., 44., 55.]],

       [[ 0., 22., 33.],
        [nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan]]])
```

Note that `nan`-values have been introduced by coercion.